# TFS 2015 - Build failed due to exception in the test assemblies

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to run a newly created Build in TFS but i am getting an error as shown in the screenshot below :

[image]

**Build Configuration**
[image]

I tried to debug the `Unit Test` project on my machine and even on the TFS server, it worked fine. So i am not able to understand if there is any configuration missing or issue in the test assemblies code?

Comment: Do you have an appropriate version of Visual Studio installed on your build server?

Comment: Yes VS2013 installed on the server.

Comment: If  build  fine on the TFS server , this may related to the build definition  configuration. Could you share related screenshot. And try to use the build service account to debug the project on the build agent again. This may also related to account permission.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I have updated the snapshot.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Yes i did debug using the service account too and it worked fine.

Comment: I took a network trace and i see that i am getting `401` on `http://abcd:8080/tfs/DEVOPS//signalr/ping?contextToken=123f4d1c-11e0-4d1a-8dba-3331b887cfc7&_=1508999381345`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since VS  is installed after the build agent configured. Then **reregister the build agent** with TFS, since the system capabilities are only discovered when the agent is first configured -- any changes made after that are not captured.

---

First you could also [Enable Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) for TFS Build vNext by add `system.debug=true` to get more detail log info for trobuleshooting.

According to your build log and configuration, the error occurs after code coverage warning.

Try to uncheck the code coverage option and trigger the build again.

As a prerequisite to using Code Coverage, the first thing to do is to install **Visual Studio Enterprise** version on the build agent.

Comment: I have disabled the code coverage. The error occurs now after the line `Starting test execution, please wait...`

Comment: @Ishan Did you get more detailed error message after enable verbose debug mode?  Generally the 401 Unauthorized error, it means that the credentials you entered were invalid for some reason.   Check if your build service account have **Build Administrators**. which has permissions to administer build resources and build permissions for the team project. Members can manage test environments, **create test runs**, and manage builds.

Comment: After enabling the debug mode i got the following details : `2017-10-26T08:01:24.7636155Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2017-10-26T08:10:34.9571301Z ##[error]
2017-10-26T08:10:34.9571301Z ##[error]Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
2017-10-26T08:10:43.6264025Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;TaskName=VSTest;code=VSTest Test Run failed with exit code255]
2017-10-26T08:10:43.6264025Z ##[error]System.Exception: VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 255`

Comment: @Ishan You are getting a  **StackoverFlowExeptions** which are very often caused by some **recursive method call that never terminates**. Try debugging those  tests to find out if recursion is the issue.

Comment: Its a simple method that saves an item into a SharePoint list and there is no loop in the code. It executes without any error on the local system as well as on the build server with System Account login when executed from VS and the execution time is 30 sec. Can it be that when the test run is called via the TFS build, it fails to authenticate to SharePoint?

Comment: @Ishan  Yes, this maybe the root cause. Check if your build service account have proper permission to SHarePoint. Besides, `VSTest Test Run failed with exit code255` this usually means  "No test runs are available for this build"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157547/discussion-between-ishan-and-patrick-msft).

Answer (score 0):

I had installed `Build Agent` before installing Visual Studio. Re-configuring the `Build Agent` resolved the issue.